# como repetir un ciclo while si no se cumple cierta condicion en el codigo?

Tags: python

Partiendo del siguiente codigo:

```
numero_1 = int(input("introduce el 1° número: "))
numero_2 = int(input("introduce el 2° número: "))
suma = numero_1  + numero_2
resta = numero_1 - numero_2
multiplicacion = numero_1 * numero_2

print("A continuación, puede realizar las siguientes operaciones:\n1) sumar los numeros 
ingresados, \n2) Restar los numeros ingresados, \n3) Multiplicar los numeros ingresados, \n4) 
Finalizar el programa  ")
eleccion = int(input(("Indique qué operación desea realizar: ")))
print(eleccion)
if eleccion == 1: 
    print(f"El resultado de sumar {numero_1} + {numero_2} es: {suma} ")
elif eleccion == 2: 
    print(f"El resultado de restar {numero_1} - {numero_2} es: {resta} ")
elif eleccion == 3: 
    print(f"El resultado de mutiplicar {numero_1} * {numero_2} es: {multiplicacion} ")
elif eleccion == 4: 
    print("Fin del programa")
```

¿como puedo hacer para crear un ciclo while que repita todo el programa si en el input "eleccion" es repondido por el usuario con cualquier cosa que no sea 1, 2, 3 o 4?

hasta ahora llegue a esta conclusion pero no es correcta.
¿cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

```
else: 
while eleccion != 1 or eleccion != 2 or eleccion != 3 or eleccion != 4: 
    print("la opcion ingresada no es correcta")
    print("A continuación, puede realizar las siguientes operaciones:\n1) sumar los numeros ingresados, \n2) Restar los numeros ingresados, \n3) Multiplicar los numeros ingresados, \n4) Finalizar el programa  ")
    eleccion = int(input(("Indique qué operación desea realizar: ")))
    print(eleccion)
    if eleccion == 1: 
         print(f"El resultado de sumar {numero_1} + {numero_2} es: 
    {suma} ")
    elif eleccion == 2: 
         print(f"El resultado de restar {numero_1} - {numero_2} es: 
    {resta} ")
    elif eleccion == 3: 
        print(f"El resultado de mutiplicar {numero_1} * {numero_2} es: 
    {multiplicacion} ")
    elif eleccion == 4: 
         print("Fin del programa")
```

Comment: Así tal cual lo estás formulando. Que el while valide si el input no es 1 ni 2 ni 3 ni 4

Comment: no logro entender como funciona el while. he intentado diferentes cosas pero no entiendo como armar el codigo. por eso recurro a ustedes

Comment: "He intentado diferentes cosas" no dice mucho. Trae tu intento o intentos junto con los errores que te salen. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: `while not eleccion in [1, 2, 3, 4]:`

Comment: ya he modificado la preguntado y agregado lo que he intentado

Comment: mi comentario es la solución. Ademá ¿por que dices que la forma en que lo has hecho no es correcta?, ¿acaso te da algún error?

Comment: christian, no entiendo en que parte del codigo que hay que poner el while como vos indicas, ni que hay que poner despues de eso para que se ejecute. El while que yo pongo se repite infinitas veces y eso no me sirve. Yo necesito que se repita solamente si el usuario ingresa algo diferente a 1,2,3 o 4. cuando lo prueba y pongo 1 me sigue repitiendo el mensaje.

Comment: reemplaza tu condición del while por la que puese en mi comentario, eso es todo

Comment: perfecto ahi lo hice y funcionó todo! muchas gracias estimado!